# 'hello' == (anything that will return true other than 'hello') in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string-comparison, ecmascript-5, triple-equals

I understand that `==` in JavaScript is comparison with type coercion. And I know that the following statements are `true`:

```
'' == false;
' ' == false;
'0' == false;
'\n' == false;
```

However, I can't get a comparison with 'hello' on the left side to be true:

```
'hello' == true; // no this is false
'hello' == false; // no this is false
'hello' == 1; // no this is false
'hello' == 0; // no this is false
```

Is there anything 'hello' can be compared to which results in `true` other than 'hello'?

Comment: No.  If you're not allowing the other thing to have `"hello"` in it, then there is nothing else that will coerce to be `==` to `"hello"`.  What is the point of this question?  Right now, it seems kind of pointless without some logic behind the question.

Comment: If you study the coercion rules, you will find that the only things that will `==` to `"Hello"` are things who have a `.toString()` method that returns `"Hello"` like this: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/hKx9x/ or this: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/KSgwb/

Comment: If you are wondering how the comparison algorithm works, you can look at it here: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3

Comment: @jfriend00: Maybe you should post the explanation as an answer.

Comment: @FelixKling - I put it in an answer.

Comment: FWIW, your comparisons are all false because `'hello'` is converted to a number, which results in `NaN`, which is not equal to anything.

Comment: Edited. It is not cheating now, is it?

Answer (score 4):

There is this one:

```
if('hello') {
  alert('true') 
}
```

This will be evaluated as `true` because the string isn't empty or `null`.

Since you want a compare:

```
'hello' == String.fromCharCode.apply(String, [104, 101, 108, 108, 111])
```

Comment: I want a comparison though. It has to be `'hello' == <something other than 'hello'>`

Comment: Updated. Compare string to bytes.

Answer (score 3):

Does this count?

```
["hello"] == "hello"  // true
```

Comment: Can't have `"hello"` in it :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's one:

```
var x = ['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'];
x.toString = function() {
    return this.join("");
}

alert(x == "Hello");   // true
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/KSgwb/

Or another:

```
var x = {
    toString: function() {return "Hello";}
}

alert(x == "Hello");   // true
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/hKx9x/

If you study the coercion rules for `==`, you will find that the only thing that will satisfy `==` with `"Hello"` is something that already is a string that is `"Hello"` or something that has a `.toString()` method that returns `"Hello"`.

That can be done in as many creative ways as you want by joining an array, returning the string directly, processing a bunch of character codes that combine to form that string, etc...  But, in the end, `.toString()` has to return `"Hello"` in order to satisfy the `==` test.

---

If you aren't allowing the thing you're comparing to to have `"Hello"` in it in any way or be able to produce that string upon demand, then NO there is nothing else that will satisfy `==` except something that produces the string `"Hello"` when asked to coerce to a string.

---

Here's a layman's description of the type coercion rules for Javascript: http://webreflection.blogspot.com/2010/10/javascript-coercion-demystified.html

---

In a nutshell, here are the coercion rules when a string is involved:

1. If both types are a string, then the comparison is `true` only if the two strings contain exactly the same characters.
2. If one is a string and the other is a number, then try to convert the string to a number and compare that to the other number.  Since `Number("Hello")` is `NaN`, this will never work for a number since NaN can't be `==` to another number.
3. If one is a string and the other is an object, call the internal method `valueOf` if it's defined or `toString` if it's not defined and compare the result of that to your string.
4. If one is a string and the other is a Boolean, convert both to a number and compare them.  Since `Number("Hello")` is `NaN`, it will never match a Boolean which will either be `0` or `1` when converted to a Number.  For example: `true == "1"`.